# Issue with large data in HTML Select tag

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Please have a look on this example of HTML `Select` with large data in one option

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stack Overflow Question 34408979</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo">0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now `select` in not able to work anymore, onclick select nothing happening even drop down menu not coming.

Issue came in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m and Firefox 43.0.1.

**Generated HTML code**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf?ln=javax.faces&amp;stage=Development"></script><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/mdf-portal-web/rfRes/skinning.ecss.jsf?db=eAH7f32ROAAH4AKQ" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/status.js.jsf?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/filter.js.jsf?ln=js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.jsf"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/mdf-portal-web/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-base-component.js.jsf"></script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/mdf-portal-web/rfRes/panel.ecss.jsf?db=eAH7f32ROAAH4AKQ&amp;ln=org.richfaces" /><script type="text/javascript">if(window.PrimeFaces){PrimeFaces.settings.projectStage='Development';}</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bsm-common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/bsm-popup.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/images/ALU.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <script>
        function hideStatusPopup() {
            console.log('hideFunc');
            //document.getElementById('hiddenForm:hiddenM1').click();
            //document.getElementById('hiddenForm:hiddenM2').click();
            .hide();
        }
        function showStatusPopup() {
            //console.log('showFunc');
            //document.getElementById('hiddenForm:hiddenM1').click();
            //document.getElementById('hiddenForm:hiddenM2').click();
            .show();
        }
        function confirmation() {
            var answer = confirm("Do you really want to Logout?")
            if (answer){
                window.location = "login.jsf";
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="blue-band"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left-submenu-main" id="left-submenu-main"></div>
        <div class="body-main">
            <div class="rf-p tabs-main" id="tabsMain">
                <div class="rf-p-b" id="tabsMain_body">
                    <style>
                        select {
                            width: 240px;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <select class="select">
                        <option value="volvo">0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345</option>
                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works on my end. El Capitan, Chrome 47.0.2526.106. Although the UI looks broken but the dropdown works.

Comment: @DigitalDouble Previously i am using JSF h:selectonemenu that also creating same issue anyhow JSF also implemented HTML tag so i tried with direct HTML tag same issue coming

Comment: It seems there is a soft limit of 2340 characters when there is no break -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rtqsLmtn/

Comment: @Abhitalks But your html code working fine for me ,if i am clicking on drop down nothing happening it look like drop down hang.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: Yes, it is 2339 characters. Just add one more character and the dropdown will go black and wonky, although it will continue to work just fine and you can select options.

Comment: @Abhitalks Do yo mean after adding another character in option drop down will not work?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: Did you try that in the fiddle I linked to? As I said, it will still work but appear wonky. And this is all when there is no break in the text. If there are appropriate breaks, then there is no presentation problem. Compare this with the previous one -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rtqsLmtn/3/ (*BTW: I am testing this with Chrome v47*)

Comment: @Abhitalks Thanks let me give you my html code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98663/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-abhitalks).

Comment: @Abhitalks added html code

Comment: It works for me, but the question is why you need that long string in a simple select element? Users can hate you because this.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Agree with that but in Network Portal sometime they have very big root Entity Name so we have to support that

Comment: So I said that it works for me. Maybe you are using an old computer?

Comment: Works fine for Firefox 47.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude :) I hope i am not .

Comment: *"sometime they have very big root Entity Name so we have to support that.."* -- @SubodhJoshi Why don't you use a radio-button list then? By forcing a wrap it would be more readable and manageable. But still, a string of 4000 characters with no spaces or breaks beats me!!!

Comment: @Abhitalks I think when they started development at that time they are not aware with this so they implemented like i mentioned but now it is deliver and issue raise then only they raised a question

Comment: You have to deliver a fix anyway, so deliver a radio-button list as part of the fix. Just an idea -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/b01bnrvo/

Comment: @Abhitalks Thanks will try to give fix with new component